# Проблема с установкой модуля Magnolia CMS

Tags: cms

После падения сервера с сайтом вход в админку перенаправляет на страницу установки модуля "Magnolia Scheduler Module". При попытке его установки получаю ошибку:

`"Error while installing or updating scheduler module. Task 'Bootstrap' failed. (ItemExistsException: a node with uuid 54b56ea3-a89c-4736-b234-b62b63b6e602 already exists!)"`

Может кто знает, как это лечится?